# Can we update sharia law

Tags: sharia, morality

There are many thing in sharia law that modern people (olny disbelievers) find outdated.
So can we update sharia law.

**They saw**
That a woman can't have equal inherentense
And why can't a woman live alone and why can she go outside alone.

Comment: Allah has hikma for all rulings, some of which we can only partially understand. Women only get half inheritance because they are supported financially by the men (husband, son, etc). It's a blessing that they get even half, alhamdulilah. If a woman were to live alone, they'd expose themselves to fitna. The husband has to live with her to protect her. Again, a real blessing. She can only go out alone when in need, within a limited distance and with permission. Again to protect her, alhamdulilah.

Comment: Ok, but I am taking about modern day. Woman these day are independent

Comment: As Muslims, we have to follow the Shariat. Not society. Not our nafs or whims. So no, you absolutely do not. Or you will become deviant and risk eternal Hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not update Shariah law, especially something which is proven through revelation, as it has been forbidden and severely condemned.

> #### وأن احكم بينهم بما أنزل الله ولا تتبع أهواءهم
>
> And judge between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:49](http://legacy.quran.com/5/49)</sup>

> #### ومن لم يحكم بما أنزل الله فأولئك هم الكافرون
>
> And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the disbelievers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:44](http://quran.com/5/44)</sup>